# SelectLayerByAttribute_management selects all of type of attribute instead of specific one?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I want to create a tool that allows a user to select all the points within a specific zip code by inputting that zip code. The code below selects ALL of the points with a zip code - which is all of them.

I've tried various iterations of the SQL expression, but this the only one that doesn't cause a crash. Please let me know if you have a solution.

---

The code below works:

```
# Author: John K. Tran
# Contact: jtran20@masonlive.gmu.edu
import arcpy
import os
from os import listdir
import csv
print "arcpy imported"


"""
Input CSV can look like:

Lat,Lon,First Name,Last Name
12.34,56.78,Joe,Smith
0.98,7.65,Jane,Doe
65.43,43.21,Bob,Sagat

Make sure 'Lat' and 'Lon' fields are the 1st and 2nd column in the CSV respectively.

"""

incsv = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)# Change this to the path of your CSV file.
outfc = r'N:\ReferenceMaterials\ArcGIS Python\Pavement Cores by County\A Interim Shapefiles' + '\\' + arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) + '.shp'  # Change this to the path of your output FC.

spatialref = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326) # Create the spatial reference object as WGS84. Can modify if desired.

#check for and erase temporary data
testData = r'N:\ReferenceMaterials\ArcGIS Python\Pavement Cores by County\A Interim Shapefiles'
if len(os.listdir(testData)) == 0:
    pass
else:
    for t in listdir(testData):
        if t.endswith('.shp'):
            arcpy.Delete_management(os.path.join(testData, t))


arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(os.path.dirname(outfc), os.path.basename(outfc), "POINT", None, None, None, spatialref)

csv.register_dialect("xls", delimiter=",", lineterminator="\n") # Register the dialect for native CSV syntax in Microsoft Excel.
f = open(incsv, "r")
reader = csv.reader(f, dialect = "xls")

headers = reader.next() # Read the first line as the header names.

for header in headers[2:]: # Add fields for remaining columns if needed. Default is TEXT field.
    arcpy.AddField_management(outfc, header, "TEXT")

cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outfc, ['SHAPE@XY'] + headers[2:]) # Create InsertCursor.
count = 0
for row in reader:
    if count % 1000 == 0:
        print "processing row {0}".format(count)
    Ycoord = row[0] # Make sure 'Lat' is in the 1st column.
    Xcoord = row[1] # Make sure 'Lon' is in the 2nd column.
    newrow = [(float(Xcoord), float(Ycoord))] + row[2:]
    cursor.insertRow(newrow) # Insert point in FC for each row in CSV.
    count += 1

del cursor
f.close()

#set variables for mxd and dataframe
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, '*')[0]

#import new shapefile into dataframe
newLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(outfc)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, newLayer, 'TOP')

#select attribute (in this case, zip code)
InputFeatureClass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
InputField = 'zipCode'
InputValue = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
whereclause = """{} = '{}'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(InputFeatureClass, InputField), InputValue)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(InputFeatureClass, "NEW_SELECTION", whereclause)
```

Comment: With this where you are getting all the results? Try running the tool in arcmap and copy as python script

Comment: I've run it as a tool and in the python window, with the same result.

Comment: what error are you getting with 1=1 arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1), 'NEW_SELECTION', "'1=1'")

Comment: Shouldn't you replace `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)` with newLayer ? @SarahKelley

Comment: I would recommend writing the script without using `arcpy.GetParameterAsText()`. Once you get the script working, convert it to a script tool. Also try `' "zipCode" = 97526 '` in the event that the `zipCode` field is an integer field rather than text.

Comment: @NettaB With the code as is, no error; it just selects all points instead of just the points with the zip code 97526. If I change the expression syntax (see below @Aaron), I get: ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression

Comment: Hi @Aaron, I've replaced `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)` with `'hi'` (the points shapefile name) and tried the formatting you suggested. I get: ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression.

Comment: @Aaron - to further clarify, I'm now just running this in the python window: `import arcpy
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('hi', 'NEW_SELECTION', '"zipCode" = 97526')`

Comment: I've tested it and it seems that arcmap indeed needs all these quotations marks. In a standalone script that I wrote, this wasn't needed.==> Do you have problem with your solution or you just want to make sure there's no way to avoid it?

Comment: What type of field is `zipCode`?

Comment: @Aaron It's a string.

Comment: @NettaB Well, as I wrote it, it's running without throwing an error - but it's also not doing what I want it to, so it's not really a solution. I want to be able to select specific points that have specific zip codes. Right now, any input just selects every point.

Comment: This answer should help you with the expression: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/261263/8104

Comment: Hi both - this works: `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('hi', 'NEW_SELECTION', ' "zipCode" = \'97526\' ')`, but I'm having trouble converting it to a tool. Not sure how to make the attribute variable without messing up the syntax.

Comment: Try using arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fcname, fieldname) to add your formatting for the field. You can also use string formatting such as `"""{} = '{}'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fcname, fieldname), zipcode)`

Comment: You'll need to surround the second brackets with single quotes since your zipcode field is text, not integer.

Comment: @smiller Thank you. Worked beautifully!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fcname, fieldname)` to add your formatting for the field.

You can also use string formatting such as

```
"""{} = '{}'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fcname, fieldname), zipcode)
```

Note: You'll need to surround the second brackets with single quotes since your zipcode field is text, not integer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the field names should be in double quotes and strings should be in single quotes - it is possible to create a valid expression with further concatenation: 
`arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1), "NEW_SELECTION", '"zipCode" in ' + "('97526')")`